# excel 2007 duplication in table

Tags: excel-2007

how i compare records in a table , to make sure its record is not duplicates. using excel 2007
i don't wan't them to delete after comparison.

Comment: entire row. yes i want to color them. I have a table columns are from A to P , and i have 500 Plus rows. i want to put condition on A,B,E,F,G I and see if in these columns any duplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iif cells, A2, A3 and so on have the data then in B2 put

> =IF(AND(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A8,A9:$A$10000,1,FALSE)),ISNA(VLOOKUP(A8,$A$1:A7,1,FALSE))),"unique","duplicate")

and copy down

Comment: I have amended my answer now I know that.